# Error handling for FilteringSelect and JsonRest

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have a dijit.form.FilteringSelect using a dojo.store.JsonRest instance as the store.

My back end service for the store gets the data from somewhere else that requires authentication. Occasionally, this authentication might fail, and I'd like to report that to the browser.

The error that get returned is JSON and the response is 404, so I can see this logged in the console.  However, I can't seem to find a way to hook into that, so I can do something useful with it, either via the FilteringSelect instance, or via the JsonRest instance.

Given the following code, where can I add an error handler function?

```
var store = new JsonRest({
    target: "/json/store/",
    idProperty: "InternalID"
});

var widget = new FilteringSelect({
    id: 'widgetId',
    store: store,
    searchAttr: 'name'
}, 'widgetId'
});
```

The version of Dojo being used is 1.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up intercepting the QueryResults returned by the store.query, and created my own Deferred with an appropriate error handler.  Similar to the FilteringSelect, I also had to trap for cancellations.

The resulting portion of code goes after the definition of the store, and before the FilteringSelect.

```
aspect.after(store, 'query', function(QueryResults) {
    Deferred.when(QueryResults, function() {}, function(err) {
        if (err.dojoType && err.dojoType == 'cancel') {
            return; // ignore cancellations
        }
        // Do custom error handling here
    });
    return QueryResults;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the `datastore.fetch()` or `objectstore.query()` manually. By default, once it is attached to the select - it will fire `.fetch()` once the select opens / starts up. Whilst doing this manually, you will also have a faster responding ui since data gets cached.

Since its not defined, the query will be a wildcard - though can be specified in the fetch configuration object as well (if a minimal snippet is needed, only for validation of successfull authentication).

The two api's are slightly different

#### with DataStore

```
var store = new DataStore({
    url: "/json/store/datastore"
});
store.fetch({
   onBegin: function(size, request) { },
   onItem:  function(item, request){ },
   onComplete: function(items, request) { },

   // youre looking for this hook
   onError: function(error, request) { }
});
```

#### or with JsonRest (OP's request)

```
var store = new JsonRest({
    target: "/json/store/",
    idProperty: "InternalID"
});

store.query(/* url query parameters, none = all */).addBoth(
  function(result) {
    console.log('success', result);
  },
  function(status) {
    console.log('error', status);
  }
);
var widget = new FilteringSelect({
    id: 'widgetId',
    store: store,
    searchAttr: 'name'
}, 'widgetId'
});
```

Comment: That doesn't quite seem to work for JsonRest, though it probably works for DataStore.  I'll double check the FilteringSelect to see if is expecting an object store or a data store.

Comment: ofc im allways mixing the two api's together as they are so similar. So, function to call in above is 'query', not 'fetch' and returns a perfectly usable promise. You will have a promise with every query and i see you've found a solution :) You run that on every query, ill add edit for that, so it allows to 'pre-cache' the store